# Beautifulsoup get multiple hrefs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href

I am trying to get the hrefs from url, put into a list and print the one of the list out. for example the third, but all I got is the third character of every href.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

newlist=[]
page = urllib.urlopen("http://python-data.drchuck.net/known_by_Kamran.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
tags = soup.find_all('a')
for tag in tags:
    newlist=tag.get("href", None)
    print newlist[2]
```

the output is : 
t
t
t
t
t
t
t...

Comment: You are reassigning `newlist=tag.get("href", None)` which is a string or None not a list. This is very basic stuff, you should consider reading a  few tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

the below prints all the `href` correctly.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

newlist=[]
page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#how-clients-are-identified").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
tags = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
for tag in tags:
    print tag['href']
```

PS: the webpage that you mentioned is not accessible, so I used the different one.